# How to create sql query with list of workers with maximum for 5 last times payments

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help me please write sql query.

there is table Payments (PaymentId, EmployeeId, Date, Payment)

-Output is List of workers with the payments, maximum for 5 last times

P.S. Without RowNumber function

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: You want a result record per employee with their maximum of the last five salaries each? ROW_NUMBER would be the natural way to solve this. Why don't you want to use it? Is this homework you want us to do for you?

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting employeeid list using this query

```
select EmployeeId,Count(EmployeeId) from Payments
Group by Employeeid
Having Count(EmployeeId)<=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query If this helps.

```
SELECT PaymentId,EmployeeId,Date,Payment FROM  Payments ,(
select EmployeeId,Count(EmployeeId) AS count from Payments
Group by Employeeid
Having Count(EmployeeId)>=5) dev WHERE Payments.Employeeid = dev.EmployeeId
```

Let me know if anything deviates

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
Declare @Payments Table
(
     PaymentId          Int Identity(1,1)
    ,EmployeeId         Int
    ,Date               Date
    ,Payment            Decimal(10,2)
)

Insert Into @Payments(EmployeeId,Date,Payment) Values
 (1,'2015-06-01',10000)
,(1,'2015-06-01',12000)
,(1,'2015-06-01',15000)
,(1,'2015-06-01',17000)
,(1,'2015-06-01',14400)
,(4,'2015-06-01',8000)
,(4,'2015-06-01',9000)
,(4,'2015-06-01',7000)
,(4,'2015-06-01',8000)
,(2,'2015-06-01',50000)
,(2,'2015-06-01',700000)


Select   EmployeeId
        ,Count(EmployeeId) 
From    @Payments As p
Group by Employeeid
Having Count(EmployeeId) >= 5
```

Comment: requested Output is List of workers with the payments, maximum for 5 last times, you output employeeid with at least 5 payments